# Social Network & Dynamic vs Static pages. Where to draw the line?

Tags: php, jquery, html

As I come to the end of my project I am starting to wonder if I made it too dynamic. I have designed this social networking site and 90% of it is based on JQuery. It looks nice, it loads fast but I started to wonder if it is too dynamic...

My concern is that basically once you log in, 95% of what you do is JQuery based therefore the user never leaves the same URL. If this is true, how is a search engine like Google supposed to index my website?

Is this the part where I ask myself what parts of the site I want to be indexed and make them static pages instead?

Basically it has occurred to me that if when you browse my site for user profiles, these profiles are displayed to you through JQuery requests, then it is safe to assume that these profiles can never be found in a Google search, because the Google spider would never see it. Is this true?

Thank you for any thoughts on this,

Vini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your site work in both "modes". For example, I'm on my dashboard and I want to check out my friend Joe's profile, there should just be an A tag with the href set to something like "/profiles/joe".

Now, `onDomReady`, when the page loads, run your javascript to go through the links and attach click handers to those links, and load the profile dynamically using your existing jQuery style.

This development style is called "progressive enhancement" and allows both search engines and human accessibility devices to work better with your website. Check it out.

Comment: Having a progress enhancement approach is something that is always preferred if it's possible, but it's also something that will take more time to develop and maintain. Depending on your target audience, it might not be worth the cost to have progressive enhancement to run without javascript.

Comment: Will do. Much like this very comment I am about to post is using JQuery, this post's URL seems to be static eg. ../social-network-dynamic-vs-static-pages-where-to-draw-the-line

Comment: The application is setup to respond to that URI, doing that in your own application depends a lot on how you are handling requests now.

Comment: Hmmm.. Wonder if HTML5 will help in this matter.

Comment: Look into some of the new history functions such as `pushState`. That can be helpful, but some of the solution it is still going to be back on the server side.